# Nav Tabs positioned at the bottom of the page with Angular Material

Tags: angular-material, tabs

I'm trying to build a tab navigation bar like the example below (copied from Ionic docs) with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Each of these tabs will lazy load different pages.

To lazy load pages on each tab, the doc suggests using `nav mat-tab-nav-bar` component. However, this component presents the tabs bar at the top of the page and I need this bar at the bottom of it.

As in the docs, the `mat-tab-group` has this attribute called `headerPosition` that can be used to position the tab bar at the bottom of the page, but it doesn't work on the `nav mat-tab-nav-bar` component.

Can anyone help me either create a tab that can open pages/components in lazy mode with `mat-tab-group` or position the `nav mat-tab-nav-bar` component at the bottom of the page?

Currently my component is:
tabs.page.html

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar headerPosition="below" >
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="activePage = page.path" [active]="activePage == page.path"> {{ page.label }} </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

tabs.page.ts

```js
// ...
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {
  readonly pages = [
    {
      path: 'page1',
      label: 'Page 1',
    },
    {
      path: 'page2',
      label: 'Page 2',
    },
  ];
  activePage = this.pages[0].path;

  constructor() { }
  // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a working example of your app on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Heres the sample.

```css
.page-container {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 378px;
}

.parent-container,
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.child-centered,
.m-auto {
    /* Magic! */
    margin: auto;   
    max-width: 430px;
    min-width: 220px;
}

div#topdiv, div#bottomdiv{
    position:fixed; 
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #CCC;        
}

div#topdiv{top:0px;}
div#bottomdiv {bottom:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="child-centered">
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
    <div style="height: 150px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <footer id="bottomdiv" class="parent-container">
      <nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="child-centered mat-tab-group-inverted-header main-nav" >
        <a mat-tab-link style="height: 80px; width: 40px;" *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
          routerLink="{{ link.location }}" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
          <div style="padding: 10px;">
            <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">{{ link.icon }}</mat-icon>
            <div>{{ link.label }}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```